# How to Change File Extension (.npy to .csv) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, numpy, export-to-csv

I have 100 files with `.npy` extenstion. What should I do to convert all of them to `.csv` via loop `for`?

Besides, how can I load all of them simultaneously to concatenate the arrays with each other to a new one?

Regards

Comment: Numpy `.npy` can contain any multi-dimensional array. `.csv`s are a rather limited format, so, what *exactly* do you have as `.npy` and what **exactly** do you want your csv to look like?

Comment: If you can get the arrays you can convert those to csv. I am not sure you can just do the files. Please tell me if you would like me to post how you can convert the arrays to csv files as an answer.

Comment: @LiamHealy yes, it would be pretty good).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Unfortunately I don`t know how should it look like. Arrays consist some sounds so I would like, based on data, to make averging the sound level totally

Comment: `npy` files are loaded into memory with `np.load` (read its docs).  Try that with a few of your files and tells us about the resulting arrays (shape, dtype).  Then we can make meaningful suggestions on how to use `np.savetxt` to write the array(s) to a `csv` file.  Read its docs and practice writing some simple arrays.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for response. Shape: `(1, 1323000)`, dtype = `float32`. 
I got the array from each file separately, but it's need to concatenate the arrays to make one big sound track that's why I need load the array from every .npy simultaneously. I thought it will be easy via loop `for`...

Comment: Sure you could loop over the `npy` files, accumulating the arrays in a list.  When done, 'stack' them into the array shape that you want.  Or you could append each array to a text file.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for converting the arrays into CSV.

`numpy.savetxt`, by the way, saves an array to a text file.

```
import numpy
a = numpy.asarray([ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ])
numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", a, delimiter=",")
```